# Search whole c drive for file type

Tags: java, file, io

Ok so part of my program searches the C drive for all mp3 files, the only problem is that it won't go into and subfolders. Here is my code so far.

```
public static List<String> ListFiles() {
   List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
   File folder = new File("C:/");
   File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

   for (File file : listOfFiles) {
       if (file.isFile()  && file.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
           String fileS = file.getName();
           files.add(fileS);
       }
   }
   return files;
}
```

Comment: Instead of being sorry about the formatting, *fix the formatting*.

Comment: you'll be needing either an iterative, or a recursive solution

Comment: If the file you find is a folder, recursively invoke yourself.  Or (slightly better in some ways) add the folder to a list of folders to examine.

Answer (score 2):

Try a recursive approach. The path is the current directory that you're in. Recursively call this on each folder and you will get to each file.

```
public void walk(String path) {

    File root = new File(path);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null) return;

    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else {
            //do what you want with files
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test whether `file` is a folder. If it is, pass it to `ListFiles` and append the return value to `files`.

For this to work, you need to change `ListFiles` to accept a `File` object as argument and start your search with this `File` instead of with "C:/"

Answer (score 0):

Look into `DirectoryStream<Path>` class and the `Files.isDirectory()` method. Basically what you want to do is to check whether each Path is a file or directory.

If it is a directory, you call your method again. Else, you continue iterating.

Globbing is also possible with a directory stream. Saves you a lot of time instead of having to manually check file extensions.

If you wish to continue with your method or with directory stream, you will need to make a few modifications to your program to accomodate recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this yourself, you need to make it recursive. Which is what Oswald is getting at. A recursive method is a method that calls itself. So when you search a folder, for each element in it, if its an mp3, add it to the list, if its a folder, call your method again passing that folder in as the input.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's Java question but why not just use Groovy and do it like:

```
static List<String> listMp3s() {
    List<String> files = []
    File rootFolder = new File('C:/')

    rootFolder.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) {
        if (it.name.endsWith('.mp3')) {
            files << it.name
        }
    }

    return files
}
```